# c# App.Config file not transforming when building for Test deployment

Tags: c#, xslt, slowcheetah

I am using slow cheetah in my app such that I can have app.config files that will transform in the same manner as web.config transforms. I have used this in other projects with no issue, but for some reason in one of my projects, the cofing file is not changing.

A sample from my App.Test.config is the following:

```
<add key="timer" value="300" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
```

And the corresponding line in my App.config file is

```
<add key="timer" value="15"/>
```

Comment: This has been posted in case someone else is having the same or similar issue they may be able to more quickly find what is happening as this is easy to overlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out that I did not include the `<AppSettings>` tag before the `<Add>` tag in the transform. So when the transform went to take place it would look for the key timer within `<Configuration>` and not `<Configuration> <AppSettings>`